Help me! How to do this in LaTeX
I did but it not similar to this picture.
\begin{eqnarray}
    \vec{\nabla_{}} \cdot \vec{E} & = & \frac{\rho}{\epsilon _{0}} \text{Gauss's Law} \label{2} \\
    \vec{\nabla_{}} \cdot \vec{B} & = & 0 \text{Gauss's Law for Magnetism} \label{3} 
\end{eqnarray}



Please post a complete compilable example. Also, you forgot to post any picture.

And don't use eqnarray, you are already using amsmath (since you're using \text). What it up with that \nabla_{}?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

You cannot achieve that image with eqnarray, but you can with align. Just remove the & after the = and place && before each of the \text. Done

Delete the space between epsilon and _.

@IanThompson that should not do anything(?)

@daleif --- True now I think about it. It does seem very odd, though.

@daleif --- I thought it worked because the space after \epsilon is ignored, but page 129 of the TeXbook shows that it works much more generally. You learn something every day. I still wouldn't use this, though!

Please also choose a question title which will help future users with the same problem to find your post.

Never use eqnarray, one reason: It does not support multiple alignment points, align does.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} & =  \frac{\rho}{\epsilon _{0}} &&\text{Gauss's Law} \label{2} \\
    \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} & =  0 &&\text{Gauss's Law for Magnetism} \label{3} 
\end{align}
\end{document}


If you want to control the spacing use \begin{alignat}{2} ... \end{alignat} instead and place spacing maro between the &&.

Thanks!!! You saved my life.
